# pixelList in detectMSERFeature in MATLAB

Tags: java, c++, matlab, mser

I'm a newbie to MSERFeatures in MATLAB, I've come to know that after using detectMSERFeatures in MATLAB I can plot the detected pixelList on graph, but the pixels are of different colors, I want to know what they represent and how can pixelList be manipulated further in any conventional programming language like C++ or Java?